# Keyup event not firing when meta key is held (Mac OSX only?) - How to handle in javascript?

Tags: javascript, macos, dom-events

Seems like others have ran into this issue [outside of the browser](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5188). I'm trying to figure out how to deal with it in my javascript code.

When I hold command (on mac) and press and let go of another key, (such as if I were to enter command-c to copy some text), the keyup event does not fire unless I let go of command first.

This affects me because my web app responds to the alt-x key combination to toggle a menu, and this is important. I'm using keyup and keydown events to track the state of which keys are pressed at any given time, so that I can toggle the menu when the user enters alt-x (and not some other combination including alt-x). It works great until I enter command-[some key] and then my program thinks I'm entering [some key]-alt-x when I enter alt-x to toggle the menu.

Does anyone have any ideas for how to deal with this situation?

I made a [code pen](https://codepen.io/duncanbritt/pen/gOeqOQG) to illustrate the problem.

```js
const pressed_keys = {};

const keydown_handler = e => {
  pressed_keys[e.code] = true;
  if (has_entered_alt_x(e)) {
    document.querySelector('div').classList.toggle('blue');
  }
};

const keyup_handler = e => pressed_keys[e.code] = false;

const has_entered_alt_x = e => {
  if (!(e.altKey && e.code == 'KeyX')) return false;

  for (const key in pressed_keys) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(pressed_keys, key)) {
      if (!['AltLeft', 'AltRight', 'KeyX', 'CapsLock'].includes(key) && 
          pressed_keys[key]) {
        return false;
      }                    
    }
  }

  return true;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
  document.addEventListener('keydown', keydown_handler);
  document.addEventListener('keyup', keyup_handler);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a decent work around I came up with, and you can try it in [this code pen](https://codepen.io/duncanbritt/pen/NWYopKB).

```js
const pressed_keys = {};

const keyup_handler = e => { 
  pressed_keys[e.code] = false;
  // In macos the keyup event doesn't fire when the Meta key is held down. 
  // So, when Meta key is lifted, assume other keys have also been lifted 
  // as well. There is a bug introduced: If the user is quick, they can 
  // hit meta-c, lift the meta key and then hit alt-x very quickly 
  // thereafter, and in this case they will be able to toggle the change 
  // while holding down some other key. This is unlikely to occur and in 
  // the event that it does, it doesn't cause problems for the application.
  if (e.key == 'Meta') {
    Object.keys(pressed_keys).forEach(key => { pressed_keys[key] = false; });
  }
}

const keydown_handler = e => {
  // In macos the keyup doesn't fire on the Meta key (command) after 
  // certain key combinations in the browser, such as
  //   M-Q : shutdown computer 
  //   M-p : print page 
  //   M-o : opens files 
  //   M-t : new tab 
  //   M-y : opens history
  // and possibly others. So, to be able to detect when this has happened, 
  // on keydown ask if the meta key is pressed using e.meta and query 
  // pressed_keys to see if the key up event has fired. If meta isn't 
  // pressed by the keyup event hasn't fired set all pressed_keys to false.
  if (!e.metaKey && (pressed_keys['MetaLeft'] || pressed_keys['MetaRight'])) {
    Object.keys(pressed_keys).forEach(key => { pressed_keys[key] = false; });
  }
  
  pressed_keys[e.code] = true;
  if (has_entered_alt_x(e)) {
    document.querySelector('div').classList.toggle('blue');
  }
};

const has_entered_alt_x = e => {
  if (!(e.altKey && e.code == 'KeyX')) return false;

  for (const key in pressed_keys) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(pressed_keys, key)) {
      if (!['AltLeft', 'AltRight', 'KeyX', 'CapsLock'].includes(key) && 
          pressed_keys[key]) {
        return false;
      }                    
    }
  }

  return true;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
  document.addEventListener('keydown', keydown_handler);
  document.addEventListener('keyup', keyup_handler);
});
```